# Accessing model attributes for each list component in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a list of objects from my `views.py` to my html template but I can't access the objects model attributes at my HTML template. Please, check the code below:

**class.py:**

```
class FOF(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    view_count = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Frame(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fof = models.ForeignKey('FOF', related_name='frame_set')
    index = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
```

**views.py:**

```
def my_fof(request, fof_name_value):
    my_list = FOF.objects.all().order_by('-rank')
    ...
    return render_to_response('uploader/my_fof.html', {'my_list':my_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I usually can access the attributes at the html file when I pass a single object but once I am passing a list of objects, it seems impossible to access those attributes.

For example, when I type `alert({{ fof_list.0 }});` it prints the object attribute name, because it was defined in the **models.py**:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

But once I try to access any of its attributes, as `pub_date`:  `alert({{ fof_list.0.pub_date }});` it returns `undefined`, as that attribute is unavailable or unreachable.

Any Idea on how to proceed to reach those attributes when passing an entire list? Or how to proper pass that list?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to place the content of attribute in a javascript variable.

```
<script>
    var pub_date = '{{my_list.0.pub_date}}';
    alert(pub_date);

    //this will also work
    alert('{{my_list.0.pub_date}}') # enclosed in single or double quotes
</script>
```

Use a `for loop` and iterate it to get each object in a template.

```
{% for obj in my_list %}
   <span>{{obj.pub_date}}</span>
   <span>{{obj.size}}</span>
   ---
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: For some reason it is not working for me. 
Using the quotes didn't change too much. Actually, instead of getting "undefined" from  alert('{{my_list.0.pub_date}}'), I am getting no value at all.

I've no idea on what I am doing wrong =(

Comment: please paste your template code on dpaste or pastebin and share link

Comment: In view you are passing as `my_list` but in template you are using `fof_list`??

Comment: yes, I changed the name just for the example, to make it more clear. But the actual name is fof_list... I am pretty sure the error is not that misspelling because it works when I type alert('{{fof_list.0}}')

Comment: Ok do some testing, in your view do `print fof_list` does it contains any elements?? In the code you have `order_by('-rank')` but `FOF` model does not have any field named as `rank`. I doubt the list is empty.

Comment: It finally worked! Thank you very much, Mr. Adnan. I will put the answer here later on. (It was a small logic error regarding to the models.py file)
Cheers =)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`for` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to iterate over an iterable and get each element in turn.